# Parse lowercase short weekday to Java 8's time DayOfWeek

Tags: java, java-time, dayofweek, date-parsing, localdatetime

I have a string, e.g. "mon" or "tue" or "sun".
I want to parse it as a `DayOfWeek` (or null if not successful).

I'm using Kotlin, but i guess the Java folks will also understand what i would like to do:

```
private fun String.parseToDayOfWeek(pattern: String = "EE") =
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.US).parse(this, DayOfWeek::from)
    } catch (e: Exception){
        null
    }
```

This doesn't work, i'm just getting `null`s.

Instead i have to sanitize the string like this before i parse it:

```
val capitalized = this.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase() }
```

This feels cumbersome.
Am i using the api wrong or is this a hefty stumbling block?

Comment: In some locales, a day-of-week name is expected to be all lowercase while in others an initial-cap is expected. In the United States, the initial-cap is expected: Mon, Tue, not mon, tue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a DateTimeFormatterBuilder and set the parseCaseInsensitive:

```
private fun String.parseToDayOfWeek(pattern: String = "EE") =
try {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern(pattern)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);

    formatter.parse(this, DayOfWeek::from)
} catch (e: Exception){
    null
}
```

Comment: Good Answer, but does not appear to be in Java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using it wrong afaics. It seems that a lower case beginning is not allowed